# Differences between time-series regression versus cross-sectional regression

Tags: regression, time-series, model-comparison, cross-section

I am currently trying to grasp the differences between time series regression and cross-sectional regression, because these terms are often used in papers about market predictability.

I understand that in time series analysis one wants to find out how a variable performs over time. In cross-sectional analysis one wants to find out which variable of many has better results than the others at a specific point in time.

Suppose, e.g., you run a series of cross-sectional regressions for each month in order to generate a time series of parameter estimates, and then follow by comparing these parameter estimates. Is it the same as running multiple time series regressions of different variables and then comparing the values?